# Urbanmapr Package in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map of the US using the urbnmapr and am having trouble merging data into the urbnmapr file.

```
library(dplyr)
library(urbnmapr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(urbnthemes)
O<-as.data.frame(rbind(c(6071,1),c(14623,1),c(18157,1),c(18155,1),c(18167,0)))
colnames(O)<-c('O','num')
P<-urbnmapr::counties
P$county_fips<-as.numeric(as.character(P$county_fips))
data<-merge(P,O,by.x='county_fips',by.y="O",all.x=TRUE)
data%>%
  filter(state_name =="California") %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = county_fips)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "#ffffff", size = .25)
P%>%
  filter(state_name =="California") %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = county_fips)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "#ffffff", size = .25)
```

The plot using the merged data looks like this:

[image]

The plot using the original data looks like this:

[image]

Notice the lines in San Bernadinho county, which is county fips 6071, which appear in the top graph but not in the bottom one. This is a consistent problem with every county in the O dataset that I merge with P to form data, I just zoomed into California to make it more visible in this post. I am guessing some kind of issue is occurring with the merging process, but I was wondering if anyone knew what was going on here?

Comment: This might deal with the type of data, looks like it might be trying to draw the data in order or by time, instead this data is not ordinal and that may confused the function

Comment: Yeah, that does look like it is the issue. I didn't notice the order variable in the P file, but apparently it does get out of order when the merge occurs.